# Scala: Help me understand List performance

Tags: performance, list, scala, big-o

[List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) Scaladoc says:

> Time: List has O(1) prepend and head/tail access.

```
val mainList = List(3, 2, 1)
val with4 =    4 :: mainList  // re-uses mainList, costs one :: instance
val with42 =   42 :: mainList // also re-uses mainList, cost one :: instance
val shorter =  mainList.tail  // costs nothing as it uses the same 2::1::Nil instances as mainList
```

What does it mean "costs one :: instance"? (The reference to `O(1)` is to provide context, that's not what I'm asking. My question is about the comment statements).

Comment: In scala beside `::` being a method of the `List` class, `::` is also a class name and represents a single element in the list. So I think they meant here a single instance of this class

Comment: @Archeg If `::` is a class name, why doesn't the following work in REPL? `scala> ::`
`:: no such command.  Type :help for help.`
`scala> Nil`
`res4: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Try `new ::(5, Nil)`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Names that are operators must be escaped with backticks in certain contexts. Try typing `\`::\`` into the REPL.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar `new ::(5, Nil)` is exactly the same as `5 :: Nil` in scala. So when you type `val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil`, you actually creating `::` instances and not an instance of `List` (but `::` extends `List`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think by `costs one :: instance` the memory consumption is meant. When you do `4 :: mainList`, scala will create a new single `::` instance. When you do `mainList.tail`, scala does not have to create anything.

This is very important to show, because for the whole block

```
val mainList = List(3, 2, 1)
val with4 =    4 :: mainList  // re-uses mainList, costs one :: instance
val with42 =   42 :: mainList
```

Scala issues only 5 `::` instances, instead of 8.

It is definitely not about performance, because you can't say that `mainList.tail` costs nothing in terms of performance.

Comment: > "Scala issues only 5 :: instances". if I understood you right, do you mean the following breakdown? (code in comment sucks, sorry).
`val mainList = 3 :: 2 :: 1 :: Nil` (3 counts of `::`)
`val with4 = 4 :: mainList` (1 count of `::`)
`val with42 =   42 :: mainList` (1 count of `::`)

Total 5 counts of `::`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes, that's correct. This code will be translated into `val mainList = new ::(3, new ::(2, new ::(1, Nil))); val with4 = new ::(4, mainList); val with42 = new ::(42, mainList)`, so that 5 `new` keywords - so 5 memory allocations

Comment: Makes sense. Also regarding your statement, "you can't say that `mainList.tail` costs nothing in terms of performance", as I quoted, the doc already says it's a `O(1)` operation. So it almost doesn't cost anything.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar True. I was referring to my previous answer, rather to something you've said. `.tail` costs almost nothing, but it can't cost exactly nothing.